# Validating a String Containing Parentheses

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a question about a string containing parentheses.  Let me suppose that a string variable cityname is @"Boston (Massachusetts).  I wonder why Xcode doesn't recognize the string inside parentheses?  In the following code, only the first case is true.

```
// cityname = @"Boston (Massachusetts)"
if ([cityname rangeOfString:@"Boston"].location==!NSNotFound){
// true
}

if ([cityname rangeOfString:@"Massachusetts"].location==!NSNotFound){
// false
}

if (cityname isEqualToString:@"Boston (Massachusetts)"){

}
```

How can I make it so that I can validate the entire string even with parentheses (and apostrophes, too?)?

Thank you,

Tom

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with parentheses. You want `[cityname rangeOfString:@"Massachusetts"].location != NSNotFound`, not `[cityname rangeOfString:@"Massachusetts"].location == !NSNotFound`. They do totally different things.

Comment: No, that really is the answer.  The only reason your first case works at all is because the value of NSNotFound happens to be 0 when it's inverted.  I can't imagine why you would ever want to write "!NSNotFound".

Comment: @TBlue -- `rangeOfString` would not be at all upset/confused by the parens.  Chuck explained why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: How do I tell if cityname and "Boston (Massachusetts)" are the same, then?  That's my question.

Comment: @TBlue Your 3rd `if` statement, using `isEqualToString:` is the proper way to see if two strings have the same value.

Comment: It looks like I need to replace all possible special characters with escape quote characters.